# hook fired once per wordpress post/page?

Tags: wordpress

In a plugin I'm writing, I'd like to enqueue a page/post specific css file (in the html `head`) for each page/post on a page.

For instance: if a page load post 44 and 56, I'd need to have:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='post-44-css'  href='http://test/wp-content/custom/post-44.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='post-56-css'  href='http://test/wp-content/custom/post-56.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I tried using the `the_post` hook but it gets called several time and some ("late") call cause the css file to be added at the bottom of `body`.

```
function_enqueuing_css($post) {
    ...
    wp_enqueue_style($ref, $url);
    ...
}

add_action( 'the_post', 'function_enqueuing_css' );
```

Answer (score 0):

*Updated answer with reworked function.*

I've used `wp_enqueue_scripts` action and included a conditional for single posts/pages. Check the corresponding codex pages for more info.
[Action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) and [`is_single` reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single).

Now your code may look like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'function_enqueuing_css');
function function_enqueuing_css() {
    global $wp_query;
    $id = $wp_query->post->ID;

    if(is_single()) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'post-'.$id, 'path-to-file-'.$id.'.css', array(), '', 'all');
    }
}
```

The same approach can be used for js files also.

Comment: Could you fix your code? The tricky parts have been left blank (ie: how do i get each post's id?)

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook improved and tested the code, should work fine now.